# Replace the potatoes in a corned beef hash with something that isn't starchy?

Tags: substitutions, potatoes, corned-beef

I am following a low-carb diet, and would like to make corned beef hash at home with left over corned beef brisket. Onions are no problem, but I would prefer to avoid root vegetables, and potatoes in particular. What would make a good substitute, in terms of texture and taste?

Comment: A diet that cuts out healthy foods?

Comment: *Some* healthy foods, for a period of time while the dieter is attempting to lose weight. As with all diets, it's a method controlled self-starvation, and compliance (getting the dieter to stick with it) is the more critical issue. No one solution works for all people: some folks are fine with calorie counting, others go Vegan, still others do the ketogenic thing. They're all proven to work - they all present challenges to keep compliant until all the weight is off. Hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used diced turnips in dishes as a replacement for potatoes. That may work if you enjoy eating turnips. Of course the taste will be much different than potatoes.

According to Wikipedia (eep, I know... but just for a rough idea):

100 grams of..
**Turnips** 7g carbs
**Potatoes** 17g carbs

Answer (score 4):

Cauliflower might work.  I've put cauliflower in a food processor to get it to a uniform small-ish size, and then stir-fried it until soft, as a low-carb substitute for rice.  Maybe you could dice it into small pieces and do the same.  Boiling or steaming instead of stir-frying may give you a softer potato-like texture.

Comment: I had an excellent hash at a diner where the potatoes were pureéd rather than diced fine, and the beef shreds and diced onion mixed in and

Answer (score 2):

Starchy is kind of the nature of hash.  I am not sure that you would still have a hash if you eliminate the potatoes, but you should get something delicious in any case.

[This low carb website](http://www.genaw.com/lowcarb/easy_cornedbeef_cabbage.html) suggests using cabbage in a hash-like dish.

Answer (score 2):

Split pea & shallot mash from the GL diet book might work. Soak 225g split peas in cold water for 2 hours, drain place in pan & cover with water bring to boil & skim. Add 1 bay leaf & 6 sage leaves (I use thyme) simmer until tender, meanwhile fry off in olive oil 3 finely chopped shallots ( I use onion) add 2 tsps cummin + 1 clove minced garlic. Fry till soft. Drain split peas & retain water. Mix shallots with s/peas & remave bay leaf. process or blend adding water to suit the consistency you like.

Comment: What does GL stand for?

Comment: @Jolenealaska : Glycaemic Load.  (ie, low-carb)

Answer (score 1):

Cubed celery would be a good start. I would mix the celery with carrots and sweet potatoes, though they are only 'less' starch.